# Send string through UDP CSharp

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp

Long story short, I have a USB GPS and I want to foward its data to an application that listen on a specific UDP port. My problem is I only found a way to send a Byte array and the application expect a string (NMEA sentence) . Is there a way to send a string instead of a byte[] with a socket.

Here's what I have so far.

```
    private void GpsPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        inputData = GpsPort.ReadExisting();
        if (inputData != String.Empty)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), new object[] { inputData });
            SendUdp(8887, "127.0.0.1", 8888, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputData));
        }
    }

    private void SendUdp(int srcPort, string dstIp, int dstPort, byte[] data)
    {
        using (UdpClient c = new UdpClient(srcPort))
            c.Send(data, data.Length, this.txtIp.Text, Int32.Parse(this.txtPort.Text));
    }
```

Comment: To send a string as a byte array, convert the string to a byte array using a specific encoding ... which is just what `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputData)` does. What does or doesn't that do?

Comment: I want to send the string "as is" not as an array of bytes. The receiving app expects a string and won't convert the byte[] into a string.

Comment: UDP deals in bytes, not in strings.